# Flutter not able send request to Springboot backend

Tags: java, flutter, spring-boot, macos, ssl

I am creating a Flutter frontend for Android. I have already created a Springboot backend which is **SSL Secured**(secured locally) and is secured by SpringbootSecurity. From the frontend I am trying to send request to my backend but local server is receiving no request.
Here is my flutter class which is sending request code,

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:test_flutter/enpoints.dart';

class ApiService {
  Future register(String username, String password) async {
    // HttpClientRequest req = HttpClientRequest()
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.parse(Endpoints.register);
      print(url);
      var response =
          await http.post(url, body: {"email": username, "password": password});
      print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        return response.body;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my Springboot Security configurations

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurations {

    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configureHttpSecurity(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authentication/**", "/public/**")
                .permitAll();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
        httpSecurity.formLogin().disable();
        httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigSource());
        // httpSecurity.cors().disable();
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
}
```

SSL configured in properties file

```
server.port=8080
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=local_ssl
server.ssl.key-store-password=keystore
server.ssl.key-password=keystore
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:local-ssl.p12
```

Now, to test the issue I also created a fresh sprinboot app with not SSL and SpringbootSecurity and exposed a `/test` api. Flutter was able to send request to this backend and get response.
Can someone tell me what is the problem with my frontend or backend code. Btw, I am using Macbook. I would also like to list potential issue which I think might cause the issue,

- Wrong Flutter code(maybe incorrect headers)
- Springboot Security not configured properly
- SSL causing the problem
- Mac is stop the request because of SSL certificate(not sure)

P.S. Springboot backed is running locally. Have tried running flutter on actual device and emulator. Firewall on Mac is turned off.

Comment: what is the value of `Endpoints.register` ?

Comment: `'https://192.168.1.33:8080/authentication/register'`